# N Queens All Solutions, Currently shows 1

Tags: java, recursion, n-queens

I wrote this program after a month of debugging and I finally got it to work, however it only prints `1` solution to the `8` queen problem, does anyone know what I can do to make it print all the solutions? Code will be helpful but if you can just point out what to change or what to add I can work with that too.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Queens
    {
    // squares per row or column
    public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8; 

    // used to indicate an empty square
    public static final int EMPTY = 0; 

    // used to indicate square contains a queen
    public static final int QUEEN = 1; 

    private int board[][]; // chess board

    public Queens() {
        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Constructor: Creates an empty square board.
        // -------------------------------------------------
        board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    }  // end constructor         

    public void clearBoard() {
        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Clears the board.
        // Precondition: None.
        // Postcondition: Sets all squares to EMPTY.
        // ------------------------------------------------- 
        for(int j = 1; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            for(int k = 1; k < 8; k++) //Sets every column in this row to 0
            {
                board[j][k] = 0;
            }
            //moves on to next row and repeats
        }
    }  // end clearBoard

    public void displayBoard() {
        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Displays the board.
        // Precondition: None.
        // Postcondition: Board is written to standard 
        // output; zero is an EMPTY square, one is a square 
        // containing a queen (QUEEN).
        // -------------------------------------------------
        placeQueens(1);
        int N = board.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == 1) 
                {
                    System.out.print("Q ");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.print("_|");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } // end displayBoard

    public boolean placeQueens(int column) {
        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Places queens in columns of the board beginning 
        // at the column specified.
        // Precondition: Queens are placed correctly in 
        // columns 1 through column-1.
        // Postcondition: If a solution is found, each 
        // column of the board contains one queen and method 
        // returns true; otherwise, returns false (no 
        // solution exists for a queen anywhere in column 
        // specified).
        // -------------------------------------------------
        if (column > BOARD_SIZE) {
            return true;  // base case
        } 
        else {
            boolean queenPlaced = false;
            int row = 1;  // number of square in column

            while ( !queenPlaced && (row <= BOARD_SIZE) )  {
                // if square can be attacked
                if (isUnderAttack(row, column)) {
                    ++row;  // consider next square in column
                } // end if
                else { // place queen and consider next column
                    setQueen(row, column);
                    queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
                    // if no queen is possible in next column,
                    if (!queenPlaced) {
                        // backtrack: remove queen placed earlier
                        // and try next square in column
                        removeQueen(row, column);
                        ++row;
                    } // end if
                } // end if
            } // end while
            return queenPlaced;
        } // end if
    } // end placeQueens

    private void setQueen(int row, int column) {
        // --------------------------------------------------
        // Sets a queen at square indicated by row and 
        // column.
        // Precondition: None.
        // Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a 
        // given row and column to QUEEN.
        // --------------------------------------------------
        row = index(row);
        column = index(column);
        board[row][column] = 1; //Queen placed on square
    }  // end setQueen

    private void removeQueen(int row, int column) {
        // --------------------------------------------------
        // Removes a queen at square indicated by row and
        // column.
        // Precondition: None.
        // Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a 
        // given row and column to EMPTY.
        // --------------------------------------------------
        column = index(column);
        for(int x = 0; x < 8 ; x++)
        {
            if(board[x][column] == 1)
            {
                board[x][column] = 0;
                x = 8;      
            }
        }

    }  // end removeQueen

    private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column) {
        // --------------------------------------------------
        // Determines whether the square on the board at a 
        // given row and column is under attack by any queens 
        // in the columns 1 through column-1.
        // Precondition: Each column between 1 and column-1 
        // has a queen placed in a square at a specific row. 
        // None of these queens can be attacked by any other
        // queen.
        // Postcondition: If the designated square is under 
        // attack, returns true; otherwise, returns false.
        // --------------------------------------------------

        //Taking 1-8 & returning 0-7 to suite array
        row = index(row);
        column = index(column);

        //Checks the rows & columns
        //Rows
        for(int i = 0; i < column && i < 8 && row < 8; i++)
        {
            //If there's a queen in that row, the queen is under attack
            if(board[row][i] == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        //Column

        for(int j = 0; j < row && j < 8 && column < 8; j++)
        {
            //If there's a queen in that column, the queen is under attack
            if(board[j][column] == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Check diagonals
        for(int i = row, j = column; i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < 8 && j < 8; i--, j--)
        {
            //checks upper diagonal
            if(board[i][j] == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for(int i = row, j = column; i < board.length && j >= 0 && i < 8 && j < 8; i++, j--)
        {
            //checks lower diagonal
            if(board[i][j] == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        //At this point the Queen is not being attacked
        return false;
    } // end isUnderAttack

    private int index(int number) {
        // --------------------------------------------------
        // Returns the array index that corresponds to
        // a row or column number.
        // Precondition: 1 <= number <= BOARD_SIZE.
        // Postcondition: Returns adjusted index value.
        // --------------------------------------------------
        return number - 1;
    }// end index

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Queens eight = new Queens();
        eight.displayBoard();
    }
} // end Queens
```

Answer (score 1):

**displayBoard** is your driving routine; instead of letting it stop after showing one solution, wrap it in a loop that continues as long as **placeQueens** can find *new* solutions.

This means that you need to adapt **placeQueens** to continue from the previous board state.  It already does this to a great degree; you just need to handle the case where it has hit the last column.  For instance, move the 8th queen down one square and keep going from where you left off -- or back up to the next legal position for the 7th queen (since you know there's no other legal spot for the 8th).

While you're doing this, you need to slightly alter the interface between these two routines, so that placeQueens can return not only each solution, but an **all done** condition.  This tells **displayBoard** to break out of the loop (the new wrapper you added).

Is that enough description to move you along?

---

EDIT after "Not really" comment ...

Perhaps the easiest wrapper to write would be in **displayBoard**.  At the top, where you have **placeQueens(1)**, instead use

```
col = 1
while(placeQueens(col)) {
   ... print the board as usual
   ... remove 8th queen; mark its position as unusable (say, with a value of -1)
   col = 8
}
```

Adapt placeQueens so that it picks up from where it left off: it will want to put that 8th queen in the same place.  When it finds that the spot is marked unusable, reset the mark and backtrack to the 7th queen.  This operation will let it continue and find all solutions.

There are cleaner ways to do this, but I think that this one sufficiently preserves your present organization.  Ideally, you'd have a driver program that cycles through the place-and-print process, but this is mostly a matter of naming and upper-level organization.

Does *this* get you moving well enough?

Comment: Not really, I was playing around with my code and I think if I can allow it to print the output once the Queens are set then removeQueen and go again until a new output is found then continue to do that somehow it might work. Can you explain further? Or help with the code.